# Using MySQL Prepared Statements and still able to do injection

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I have a form to insert data into MySQL.

I'm running prepared statements to do this, but somehow I'm still able to do injection. I'm new to MySQL, so I might be missing something.

```
<?php

include_once 'db.php';

      $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
      $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastname']);
      $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone']);
      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
      $nif = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nif']);
      $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
      $postal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['postal']);
      $distrito = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['distrito']);

      $sql = "INSERT INTO clients (name, surname, phone, mail, nif_id, address, postal, distrito) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
      $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
      if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "SQL error";
      } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssisss", $first, $last, $phone, $email, $nif, $address, $postal, $distrito);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      }
```

**EDIT**

This happens when running `name=TEST&lastname=TEST&email=TEST&phone=9999999999&nif=&address=&postal=&distrito=Lisboa` on the file above through it's URL `https://.../includes/addclient.php`

Am I missing something?

Comment: What were you able to inject that leads you to believe that your code is not working as it should?

Comment: @Dave when I run `name=TEST&lastname=TEST&email=TEST&phone=9999999999&nif=&address=&postal=&distrito=Lisboa` on the url, I am able do insert these values on the table

Comment: In the context of your question that makes  no sense. You have nothing in your question related to a URL or retrieving values from a URL.

Comment: If you are sending things via URL you need to use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`. Regardless, the values would be retrieved and inserted into the database. That is the desired behavior not "injection" as you call it.

Comment: @Dave, oh ok! I thought `$_GET` wouldn't insert the values into the table.

Comment: You don't have to escape strings you use as bind parameters. The parameters are not being concatenated into the SQL string. All the `mysqli_real_escape_string` calls are unnecessary.

Comment: Neither `$_GET` nor `$_POST` insert anything. They are simply the mechanism to get data from other places (a URL or a form).

Comment: @Schwern isn't the `mysqli_real_escape_string` how I get the data on the form?

Comment: You get form data simply by referencing `$_GET` or `$_POST`. You may have seen examples using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` which is one way of making the form data safe for using in an SQL query. But it's both **simpler to code and more secure** to use parameters _instead_ of `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. You don't want to use both methods, because the data in the database will have backslashes in it.

Answer (score 1):

Combining together all the comments...

[SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is when someone *maliciously* crafts a value that adds to a SQL statement. This is only a concern when building up SQL queries using string concatenation. For example...

```
$first = $_POST['name'];
$last = $_POST['lastname'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (name, surname) VALUES ('$first', '$last')";
```

If someone claims their first name is `Foo` and their last name is `'); delete from clients; select('` you have a problem.

```
INSERT INTO clients values ('Foo', ''); delete from clients; select('');
```

There's two ways to protect against this. First is to escape anything that might be a SQL meta-character like quotes and semi-colons. That's what [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) attempts to do.

```
  $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
  $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastname']);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO clients (name, surname) VALUES ('$first', '$last')";
```

Now when they pass in `'); delete from clients; select('` it will be escaped probably to `\'\)\; delete from clients\; select\(\'` neutering it so it cannot jump out of its quotes. This is not 100% effective, and it makes it difficult to audit the code to make sure you've accounted for all possible injection vectors.

The better way is to use bind parameters. Because you're no longer concatenating strings together it avoids the problem entirely. Each parameter is explicitly passed to the database as a value. This means it's safe to pass your form parameters straight in. Escaping them first might mangle the values with extra backslashes.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST['name'], $_POST['lastname']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

In addition to not needing to escape every value, it makes the code easier to audit for SQL injection. Anything that's building a query with string concatenation is suspect and there are automated tools which can warn you about this.

Comment: Mostly +1 but SQL injection is not necessarily malicious. It could be the result of an innocent mistake on the part of the user. It doesn't always result in a data breach — it could just result in a runtime error.